# How to use Linq to check a list of objects property have allowed values from another list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class Person, in this class i have some properties. One of these properties is string Role.
the user can input the role in an xml file that i should parse.
I have a List of allowedRoles where the allowed roles are hardcoded. I want to check if the Role property and compare it to the allowedRoles list.
I want to use linq to filter out the unallowed Roles.

```
public class Person
{
   Public string Name {get; set;}

   Public string Role {get; set;}
}
```

I have a list with allowed roles

```
var allowedRoles = new List<string>{"Developer","Admin","Recruiter"};
```

At a later stage i when i parsed the xml. I get a list of Person where i need to validate the role property against my AllowedRoles list. I dont want to use a loop. I would prefer using a linq expression to filter out the unvalid roles where Im left with a list of Persons that have the allowed roles.
so I have a list of Person:

```
var persons = new List<Person>();
```

How do i use my AllowedRoles list to filter out the unallowed Roles from Persons?

Comment: Note that Linq is just going to do loops under the covers.  Also I'd recommend making `allowedRoles` a `HashSet<string>`, though if it's never more than 3 it's not a big deal.

Comment: yes I know that it's looping under the covers.However, I'm trying to learn using linq. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way of achieving this would be to use `Where` combined with `Contains`, for example:

```
var filteredPeople = persons.Where(p => allowedRoles.Contains(p.Role));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
var allowedPersons = persons.Where(p => allowedRoles.Any(r => r == p.Role));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq `Where` extension method with the `Contains` method of `List<string>` like that:

```
static void Test()
{
  var persons = new List<Person>
  {
    new Person { Name = "1", Role = "Admin" },
    new Person { Name = "2", Role = "Customer" },
    new Person { Name = "3", Role = "Recruiter" },
    new Person { Name = "4", Role = "User" },
  };

  var allowedRoles = new List<string> { "Developer", "Admin", "Recruiter" };

  var personsAllowed = persons.Where(person => allowedRoles.Contains(person.Role));

  foreach ( var person in personsAllowed )
    Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
}
```

To get unallowed simply use the not operator:

```
var personsUnallowed = persons.Where(person => !allowedRoles.Contains(person.Role));
```

The contains method assumes that strings identically matches and are same case.

*Output allowed*

```
1
3
```

*Output unallowed*

```
2
4
```

Answer (score 0):

With an extension method, you can write it in a more expressive way:

```
var filteredPeople = persons.Where(p => p.Role.IsIn(allowedRoles));
```

And your extension method:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
 {
 public static bool IsIn<T>(this T item, List<T> list)
  {
  return list.Contains(item);
  }
 }
```

This reads nearly like real english: "where role is in allowed roles".